# Android saving data from sensor in internal storage file not found

Tags: java, android, save, android-sensors

I am now working on my first android project, including saving data from the sensor on the phone for 15 minutes after the mainAcitivity called. Considering sometimes there may not be sd card in the phone, I decided to store the files on internal storage.

Now I have stuck it these problems for a few days:

1. After saving the data I have returned the directory with `getFilesDir()`, but I couldn't find the showed route anyway.
   [screen shot after running service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1ZJJ.jpg)
   /data/user/0/com.example.liya.medicinecalendar/files/201807100711.txt
2. The service according to the toast sometimes starts and ends not as wished.

In MainActivity.class I just used

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SaveSensorService.class));
```

I didn't create a thread because I don't wanna let screen activity and service run at the same time.

Here is my SaveSensorService.class

```
public class SaveSensorService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SaveSensorService";

    private Float xValue, yValue, zValue, xGyroValue, yGyroValue, zGyroValue;
    SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer, mGyro;


    private SimpleDateFormat Date_Format,Newtime_Format;
    private  Calendar calendar;
    private String StartTime, StopTime, CurrentTime, FileName;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: SaveSensorService started.");

        Newtime_Format = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        StartTime = Newtime_Format.format(calendar.getTime());
        CurrentTime = StartTime;
        //calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);//save sensor data for 15min
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND,60);//for test
        StopTime = Newtime_Format.format(calendar.getTime());
        Toast.makeText(SaveSensorService.this, StartTime+" SaveSensorService is running",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Initializing Sensor Services");
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        if (accelerometer != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(SaveSensorService.this, accelerometer, 5000000);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Registered accelerometer Listener");
        } else {
            xValue = null;
            yValue = null;
            zValue = null;
            ;
        }

        mGyro = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
        if (mGyro != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(SaveSensorService.this, mGyro, 5000000);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Registered Gyro Listener");
        } else {
            xGyroValue = null;
            yGyroValue = null;
            zGyroValue = null;
        }

        if ((accelerometer!=null || mGyro != null)&&CurrentTime.compareTo(StopTime) < 0) {
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            CurrentTime = Newtime_Format.format(calendar.getTime());
            saveSensor();
        }

        else  {
            stopSelf();
            Toast.makeText(SaveSensorService.this,"Time's up or device not support."+ CurrentTime,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: SaveSensorService stopped.");
        Toast.makeText(SaveSensorService.this,"Sensordaten wurden gespeichert."+ CurrentTime,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    /*********** save the sensor data during the set time - START *******************/

        public void saveSensor () {

            //create a new file, named by the current time
            Date_Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
            FileName = Date_Format.format(calendar.getTime())+".txt";

            try{
            FileOutputStream fos = null;


                //to prevent that the file fail to be read or created, use catch to print the error
                // write in txt,

                fos = openFileOutput(FileName, MODE_APPEND);
                //write the first line - description
                fos.write("xValue\tyValue\tzValue\txGyroValue\tyGyroValue\tzGyroValue\r\n".getBytes()); //define the first line

                    //append the sensor data in the file
                    fos.write((xValue + "\t" + yValue + "\t" + zValue + "\t" + xGyroValue + "\t" + yGyroValue + "\t" + zGyroValue + "\r\n").getBytes());
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: file ist written.");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to " + getFilesDir() + "/" + FileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }



    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        Sensor sensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

        //get accelerometer data
        if(sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged: X:" + sensorEvent.values[0] + "Y:" + sensorEvent.values[1] + "Z:" + sensorEvent.values[2]);

            xValue = sensorEvent.values[0];
            yValue = sensorEvent.values[1];
            zValue = sensorEvent.values[2];

        }

        //put gyrocope data
        else if(sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged: XG:" + sensorEvent.values[0] + "YG:" + sensorEvent.values[1] + "ZG:" + sensorEvent.values[2]);

            xGyroValue = sensorEvent.values[0];
            yGyroValue = sensorEvent.values[1];
            zGyroValue = sensorEvent.values[2];

        }

    }

    /***************** save the sensor data during the set time - END *************************/

}
```

And here is my AndroidMainifest.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.liya.medicinecalendar">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/foreground"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CalendarActivity"></activity>
        <service android:name=".SaveSensorService"
        android:enabled="true"/>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
        <service android:name=".AlarmService"
            android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I will be so grateful if someone can give me some advice to solve this problem when saving data. Thank you so much in advance!